# Interpret Characteristic Properties (iOS and BLE)

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am reading characteristic properties from a BLE device from my iPhone.

However, some of the properties I am seeing (like 0xA, 0x22) are not in the enumerated list that Apple provides.  Are these properties a combination of 2 or more enumerated values? Or are these custom properties from the manufacturer? Need guidance on this.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/#//apple_ref/c/econst/CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites):

> Values representing the possible properties of a characteristic. Since
>   characteristic properties can be combined, a characteristic may have
>   multiple property values set.

In other words, a characteristic may have more than one property. That makes sense as you can, for example, have a characteristic which can be read (`CBCharacteristicPropertyRead`) and written to (`CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite`).

In this case the value of `CBCharacteristic`'s `properties` would be the bitwise OR of `CBCharacteristicPropertyRead` and `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite`, which is `0xA`.