# iOS central writing is not permitted

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am a ios developer. 
I can take a value from arduino sensor. But i cannot send a message by using the following the method.

```
[peripheral writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

"`dataToWrite`" value is alloc by using `NSString`*

```
NSString* data = @"1";
NSData* dataToWrite = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and the following code is full code of "DiscoverCharacteristics in service"

```
//DISCOVER CHAR
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {NSLog(@"DISCOVER_CHAR - Error");return;}

    NSString* data = @"1";
    NSData* dataToWrite = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    for (CBCharacteristic * characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        NSLog(@"DISCOVER_CHAR - Characteristic : %@",characteristic);
        [peripheral writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
    }
}
```

In this point, I want to summarize my question.
My Question is 
"Even i used the [`Peripheral writeValue:forCharacteristic:type`] Method. why an error message is shown in log monitor? " Like "**Writing is not permitted**."

Do i need to get some permission to writing the message for an Arduino?
**OR** I have to change my following code?
**OR** I have a problem in Arduino(Acutally, Arduino can get a message from other device... so, Arduino source code is fine. maybe...)

```
NSString* data = @"1";
NSData* dataToWrite = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I'm a bit of a bluetooth noob. So it's probably something obvious I've overlooked but any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!:)

Comment: You need to check the properties of the discovered characteristic. Does it support write ?  Does it support write with response ?

Comment: Thank you! your comment. but i have a question how i check the properties of the discovered characteristic. Can you help me? Do i need to write a code more or just i have to check the properties in some area?

Comment: You need to check the `properties` property on the CBCharacteristic that you discover - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBCharacteristic/properties  Look for value `Write` or `WriteWithoutResponse`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you a lot!!!!!!! Paulw11. Finally, i sent a data from iphone to Arduino. what i checked properties of my characteristic is 
`<CBCharacteristic: 0x13564a680, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = (null), notifying = NO>`. 
My characteristic's properties = 0x16. but i can not find a 0x16 in enum of properties. Still, I don't know the 0x16 meaning. Someone said that "Values representing the possible properties of a characteristic. Since characteristic properties can be combined, a characteristic may have multiple property values set." 
URL: [Interpret Characteristic Properties (iOS and BLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768645/interpret-characteristic-properties-ios-and-ble) .
 Anyway I could find a solution by PaulW11 help! How i can do it? Here is my way of solution.
At first, My method is `[peripheral writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:characteristic *type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse]*;`.
The problem code is type field. I had to understand the type. The type has a meaning of write, read and so on. So, I changed the type from `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` to `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite`. That is what i did.
 `[peripheral writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:characteristic *type:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite*];`
Thank you again! Paulw11

Comment: From the documentation you can see that 16 = 0x10 = CBCharacteristicNotify, so you can't write to it, you can only request notification when it changes

Comment: But the parameter of type: is 'CBCharacteristicWriteType'. But you are passing a 'CBCharacteristicProperties' to it ?

Comment: What I have to do for Swift 4.2? Because there is only two types .withResponse and .withoutResponse

Answer (score -1):

try to print error inside following method:

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
    didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
             error:(NSError *)error 
{ 
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

If the error is "Writing is not permitted", then you might not writing the data correctly.Convert the string value in this format

```
NSData* data = [@"string_to_write" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

And try this:

```
[self.peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

Hope it works!!