# Swift Bluetooth Writing is not permitted

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

i have tried to write command form iphone to BT ble with Bluejay library, show as below

```
func write(command: Command) {
    let weakSelf = self
    Utils.delay(0.3) {
        debugPrint("[\(self.getTodayString())]Writing to device: \(command.string)");
        debugPrint("hunter: weakSelf.bdeCharacteristics = \(weakSelf.bdeCharacteristics) and bdeService= \(weakSelf.bdeService) , and isConnected = \(weakSelf.isConnected)");

        weakSelf.bluejay.write(to: weakSelf.bdeCharacteristics, value: command.string) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                debugPrint("Write to sensor location is successful.")
            //case .cancelled:
                //debugPrint("Cancelled write to sensor location.")
            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint("Failed to write to sensor location with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

while write command, log as below:

> "[2020-1-13 0:30:24]Writing to device: SystemOn:\n\0"
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.247 [Bluejay] [main] > Requesting write on Characteristic: 0000FFB2-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, Service: 0000FFB0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB...
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.248 [Bluejay] [main] > Queue will start Bluejay.DiscoverService...
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.248 [Bluejay] [main] > Queue has removed Bluejay.DiscoverService because it has finished.
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.249 [Bluejay] [main] > Queue is empty, nothing to update.
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.249 [Bluejay] [main] > Queue will start Bluejay.DiscoverCharacteristic...
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.250 [Bluejay] [main] > Bluejay.WriteCharacteristic added to queue with UUID: 15A4B937-7BCB-4F02-B6D5-96E04D480320.
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.250 [Bluejay] [main] > Queue has removed Bluejay.DiscoverCharacteristic because it has finished.
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.251 [Bluejay] [main] > Queue will start Bluejay.WriteCharacteristic...
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.252 [Bluejay] [main] > Started write to Characteristic: 0000FFB2-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, Service: 0000FFB0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB on 845E44D2-42EE-7B03-CC5D-10675DF5DB09.
>   2020-01-13 00:30:24.253 [Bluejay] [main] > Failed writing to Characteristic: 0000FFB2-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, Service: 0000FFB0-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB on 845E44D2-42EE-7B03-CC5D-10675DF5DB09 with error: Writing is not permitted.
>   "Failed to write to sensor location with error: Writing is not permitted."

result is show:**Failed to write to sensor location with error: Writing is not permitted.**

*note: project original form swift 3 upgrade to swift 4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to 
[i found this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918988/ios-central-writing-is-not-permitted)

CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse has changed to withoutResponse after swift 4

so i replace withResponse  with withoutResponse , this problem is solved.